# Remove the identical values, and leave only different

Tags: pandas, dataframe, html-table

I would like to know if there is more optimal solution to leave the different value (to easily catch them) and to remove identical values under some columns.

```
    merged = pd.merge(us_df, gb_df, how='outer', indicator=True)

    res = pd.merge(merged[merged['_merge'] == 'left_only'].drop('_merge', axis=1),
                   merged[merged['_merge'] == 'right_only'].drop('_merge', axis=1),
                   on=us_df.columns.tolist()[0:col_range],
                   how='outer',
                   suffixes=('_US', '_GB')).fillna(' ')

    cols = [col for col in res.columns.tolist() if '_US' in col or '_GB' in col]
    sorted_cols = [col for col in res.columns.tolist() if '_US' not in col and '_GB' not in col] + sorted(cols)
```

I get this table (**res**):

| Id | ages_GB | ages_US | salary_GB | salary_US |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 45 | 45 | 34 | 67 |
| 43 | 12 | 11 | 65 | 65 |

So far, I used this iteration:

```
    cols = [ages_US, salary_US, ages_GB, salary_GB]
    for i, row in res.iterrows():
        for us, gb in zip(cols[:len(cols) // 2], cols[len(cols) // 2:]):
            if row[us] == row[gb]:
                res.at[i, us] = res.at[i, gb] = ' '
```

to get the result (where identical values under columns in **cols** are replaced with " " (space)):

| Id | ages_GB | ages_US | salary_GB | salary_US |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 |  |  | 34 | 67 |
| 43 | 12 | 11 |  |  |

Is there another method to get the similar result?

Answer (score 0):

Given your example I think `loc` offers a simpler solution assuming you want to compare two sets of columns.

I will first recreate a reproducible example of your dataset (I would recommend you create this in future questions as it makes it easier to understand and answer you question: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

```
d = {
'ages_GB': [45, 12],
'ages_US': [45, 11],
'salary_GB': [34, 65],
'salary_US': [67, 65]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

##### Initial DataFrame

```
   ages_GB  ages_US  salary_GB  salary_US
0       45       45         34         67
1       12       11         65         65
```

The simplest solution I can think of is to use `loc` to just reassign records to `""` or `NaN` where `ages_GB == ages_US` & `salary_GB == salary_US`.

```
df.loc[df.ages_GB == df.ages_US, ['ages_GB', 'ages_US']] = ["", ""]
df.loc[df.salary_GB == df.salary_US, ['salary_GB', 'salary_US']] = ["", ""]
```

##### Output

```
  ages_GB ages_US salary_GB salary_US
0                        34        67
1      12      11
```

Answer (score 0):

For a generic method, you can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `axis=1` using the columns prefixes, and get the duplicated values to use with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
prefix = df.columns.str.extract('^([^_]+)', expand=False)
# ['Id', 'ages', 'ages', 'salary', 'salary']

m = df.groupby(prefix, axis=1).transform(lambda s: s.duplicated(keep=False))

out = df.mask(m, '')
```

Output:

```
   Id ages_GB ages_US salary_GB salary_US
0   6                        34        67
1  43      12      11
```

Intermediate `m`:

```
      Id  ages_GB  ages_US  salary_GB  salary_US
0  False     True     True      False      False
1  False    False    False       True       True
```